# C# How to change the loaded dbSet, with Include method depending on the request?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, oop, generics, dbcontext

I know that there is many questions here in stack overflow that have the same topic I read almost all of them but they made me more confused about this.

Please Take a look at the code below

```
if (request.PlaceType == PlaceType.Doctor)
{
        var place = db.Doctors.Include(d => d.Reservations).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == request.PlaceId);
        place?.Reservations.Add(request.ToReservation(userId));
}
else if (request.PlaceType == PlaceType.Hospital)
{
        var place = db.Hospitals.Include(d => d.Reservations).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == request.PlaceId);
        place?.Reservations.Add(request.ToReservation(userId));
}
```

Did you notice that The only change between the 2 if statements is just the dbSet ?

**My Question** is : Is there a way to achieve the same result without using if at all, I have 4 places entities, I just posted 2. what If the client asked to add more places in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This makes me wonder if you wouldn't be much better off with just one table and one entity for `Place`, instead of spreading them over multiple tables that apparently may grow in number...

Still, a solution could be this. EF entity types are always Partial Classes, so you can add to it and make them inherit an interface `IPlace` that looks like this (fill in the placeholders):

```
interface IPlace
{
    <<IdType>> Id { get; set; }
    <<ReservationType>> Reservations { get; set; }
    // perhaps more properties
}
```

Then shorten the code like this:

```
DbSet<IPlace> dbSet = null;
if (request.PlaceType == PlaceType.Doctor)
    dbSet = db.Doctors;
else if (request.PlaceType == PlaceType.Hospital)
    dbSet = db.Hospitals;

if (dbSet == null) throw new Exception("Unsupported PlaceType");

var place = dbSet.Include(d => d.Reservations).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == request.PlaceId);
place?.Reservations.Add(request.ToReservation(userId));
```

Comment: Assignment `DbSet<IPlace> dbSet = db.Doctors` will not compile because `Doctors` are of type `DbSet<Doctor>` and `DbSet` is not covariant on its generic type argument.

Answer (score 0):

I am Sure reflection is what you need, but I can't test my code right now so I'm not sure if what I wrote will definitely work.. but it should be at the very least something like that.

```
     PropertyInfo[] placeTypes;
        placeTypes = typeof(PlaceType).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                                  BindingFlags.Static);
var requestedType = placeTypes.SingleOrDefault(x=> x == request.PlaceType);

PropertyInfo context = typeof(dbContext).GetPropertie(requestedType.Name + "s");

var place = context.Include(d => d.Reservations).FirstOrDefault(d => d.Id == request.PlaceId);
        place?.Reservations.Add(request.ToReservation(userId));
```

Comment: Yes, I think reflection is what I need, but Your code Not working, Could you please try to update it when you have time, thx for your help